# SQL Insert row in related when a row is inserted in master

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, cascade, relation

After setting a **foreign key** relation we can select the action to perform when the row is deleted/updated in master table (foreign key origin).

My question is:

Can I set a relation so when a record is inserted in a master table all related tables insert a new row with the foreign key? I'm looking for this solution because it would be really safer to create records with dependancies. I'm already creating this tree of dependant records manually using PHP.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are basically describing a trigger, so please read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html

Hope that helps.